# viewstate in reporting services

Tags: postback, viewstate, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

I work as a consultant at a company that have around 30 reports in a reporting services 2005 server. All of the reports use around 10 parameters to change the data loaded into the report. The parameters is depending on eachother also.

The problem is that the reports causes long loadtimes for booth changing parameter and processing/loading the final report. On top of this the report generate a big viewstate around **110 000 char** long, and this probably impact the long loading time when report is being postbacked to server.

I have checked t-sql and stored procedures processing time and they look normal when i use sql profiler. So it must have to do with the rendering process and postback of report with the heavaly viewstate...

Can you disable viewstate in reporting services reports for different controllers like you can in asp.net webforms ? Or do end user have to live with the long loading times.

Comment: the problem was solved when we minimized the data that was loaded in dropwdown parameters. In the beginninig some of the dropwdown parameters had over 100 different values wich caused long client rendering and viewstate and that was a big bottle neck of the long loadtimes and postbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have issues via our web load balancer.

We have some big reports with 10-20 parameters but we're OK on Dev/UAT but prod is a lot slower and parameter post backs are bad.

On a corporate network, 110k is peanuts so it may be infrastructure/config rather then RS web app related

Memo to me: I really should fix this...